# I faced an error while creating a circle object in my driver code

Tags: java, oop

While making a circle class program. I faced an error in my driver section. The error is, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
LastLab cannot be resolved to a type
LastLab cannot be resolved to a type
at Task1.Mainclass.main(Mainclass.java:18)

This is my method and data field code

```
public class Circle {

    private final double PI = 3.14159;

    private double radius;

    public void Circle(double rad) {
        radius = rad;
    }

    public void setRadius(double rad) {
        radius = rad;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public double getDiameter() {
        return radius * 2;
    }

    public double getCircumference() {
        return 2 * PI * radius;
    }
}
```

This is my driver code

```
public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get the radius from user;
        System.out.print("Enter the radius of your circle:");
        double radius = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Create a circle object.
        LastLab circle = new LastLab();

        // Get data from circle and display it
        System.out.println("The circle's area is: " + circle.getArea());
        System.out.println("The circle's diameter is: " + circle.getDiameter());
        System.out.println("The circle's circumference is: " + circle.getCircumference());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Circle circle = new Circle();
```

You have incorrect declaration: `LastLab circle = new LastLab();`

And you have incorrectly declared constructor for `Circle`. Check this out:

```
public class Circle {

    private static final double PI = 3.14159;
    private final double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public double getDiameter() {
        return radius * 2;
    }

    public double getCircumference() {
        return 2 * PI * radius;
    }
}

public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the radius of your circle: ");

        Circle circle = new Circle(sca.nextDouble());

        System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "The circle's area is: %.2f\n", circle.getArea());
        System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "The circle's diameter is: %.2f\n", circle.getDiameter());
        System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "The circle's circumference is: %.2f\n", circle.getCircumference());
    }
}
```